# SwiftUI: Minimum presentation detent for sheet

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am presenting a sheet in my app and setting presentation detent values to medium and large. The sheet also shows slider handle.

I want to sheet to expand to large/full size and minimize it to medium height, but I never want to close the sheet when dragged down further. Right now, if I drag the bottom panel/sheet when it's medium height, then the bottom panel closes. How I set minimum height or avoid closing the bottom panel like Apple Maps?

***Code:***

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show sheet") {
                showSheet = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            SheetView().presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @State var largerSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
            Text("Testing detents on bottom sheet.")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: `interactiveDismissDisabled()`?